# When to use binary mode 'rb' instead of text 'rt' for reading files

Tags: python-3.x, file, text, gzip

With Python 3, I always open files in text mode (`rt`) even if they are `gzip`'ed, maybe because I'm usually interested in parsing the lines and it seems to work flawlessly (?). For example:

```
with open(filename, 'rt') as fh:
    # do something

# or when gziped
import gzip
with gzip.open(file, 'rt') as fh:
    # do something
```

However, it is also possible to read files in binary mode (`rb`), and was wondering when one approach should be preferred over the other. What are the advantages of open files for reading in binary mode? Is it better/faster to process the lines afterwards?

Comment: The only difference is python converts line endings in text mode.

Comment: @PeterWood Not the _only_ difference. Reading in binary mode gives you bytes instead of decoding the bytes to a unicode string.

Comment: Ah, my lack of experience with Python 3 is showing.