# downloading EXE File with requests module

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I am trying to download **EXE** file with **requests**, I am getting the file content then create a new file with python and write the content inside it, but it is showing error when I am trying to lunch the app. If someone could help me please I will be very appreciate this.

```py
    r = requests.get("my download").text
    f = open('zixa.exe', 'w', encoding="utf-8")
    f.write(r)
    os.startfile(path of the file)
```

**Windows ERROR:**

[image]

Comment: You need to use “binary” mode to write anything that’s not a text file.  Otherwise python will corrupt your file trying to interpret as text.  `open(…, ‘wb’)`

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602639/when-to-use-binary-mode-rb-instead-of-text-rt-for-reading-files  except dealing with reading in text vs binary mode.

Comment: what is the mode of binary? f = open('zixa.exe', '???', encoding="utf-8")

Comment: ‘wb’, just like I said in my comment. And encoding is irrelevant.  That has no meaning outside of text.

Comment: And you probably need to get binary data from requests, not “text”; looks like you probably want `.content` with a quick glance at the documentation.  I am not familiar with this library, so you’ll have to try it yourself.  See the [docs](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content) for more information.

Comment: oh i didnt pay attention my bad, thank you i will have a look on this.